# Update web-ex host account from admin account using web-ex XML API

Tags: webex

I want to update host accounts from a admin account.
I'm trying to do it using "SetUser" XML API of webex.
I can do it successfully using the host credentials to update host account, But unable to do the same when I user admin credentials.
Below is the code I've tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serv:message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:serv="http://www.webex.com/schemas/2002/06/service">
  <header>
    <securityContext>
      <siteName>siteName</siteName>
      <webExID>Admin_webExID</webExID>
      <password>Admin_Pssword</password>
    </securityContext>
  </header>
  <body>
    <bodyContent xsi:type="java:com.webex.service.binding.user.SetUser">
    <!-- I 'm trying to change following options for Host_User -->
      <WebExID>Host_User</WebExID>
      <privilege>
        <teleConfCallIn>true</teleConfCallIn>
        <teleConfCallInInternational>true</teleConfCallInInternational>
        <teleConfTollFreeCallIn>true</teleConfTollFreeCallIn>
        <teleConfCallOut>true</teleConfCallOut>
        <teleConfCallOutInternational>true</teleConfCallOutInternational>
      </privilege>
      <meetingType>16</meetingType> 
      <meetingType>214</meetingType>
    </bodyContent>
  </body>
</serv:message>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to login to the Site Administration page here ​`https://{sitename}.webex.com/admin` and modify users, the same account should work via the API.

Also if your site is using SSO, you must use the Webex username and password (can be verified against above admin URL) rather than your SSO credentials.